# official lexical analyzer generator for javascript

Tags: javascript, compiler-construction, flex-lexer, lexer

I am studying compilers, I wonder if there is a standard lexical analyzer generator for javascript language.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: it's simple just want the suggestion of lexical analyzer generator based on your experience.
I had to post a code because the simple question was not being accepted by stackoverflow.

Comment: Does that code have any relevance at all?

Comment: no, as I said, I only posted because the system required a complex question

Comment: There is no "standard" generator. Lexical analysis is not considered part of the Javascript standard library. (Regular expressions are, which can help with lexical analysis, but more manual work is necessary.) There are several packages which can be used to generate lexical analysers, but SO guidelines discourage questions which ask for software recommendations. It should be easy to find some packages with an internet search engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Antlr 4](https://www.antlr.org/) is able to generate parsers using [JavaScript](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/javascript-target.md) as target language.